# Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 instance when using temporary role credentials

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Under security best practices, AWS does not recommend using AccessKey and Secret from within an EC2 instance to gain access to various services. Instead, you are meant to assign required permissions to the IAM role that is associated with the EC2 instance.

I am currently attempting to do just that using the .NET sample code provided here: [Making requests using IAM user temporary credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/AuthUsingTempSessionToken.html)

I have copied the .NET code into a new .NET 6 console application, and I have set the bucket name to the arn of an S3 bucket I have in the account I am running the EC2 instance in.

I have set the Region Endpoint to the region that contains my S3 bucket.

I compiled the code, published it, and copied the published folder into my EC2 instance. Then I ran the exe.

Unfortunately, it fails with the error: "Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service."

Stack trace:

```
Listing objects stored in a bucket
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.)
 ---> Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.
   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()
   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentials()
   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentialsAsync()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.DocSamples.S3.TempCredExplicitSessionStartTest.GetTemporaryCredentialsAsync() in C:\Code\TestAwsEC2TemporaryCredentials\TestAwsEC2TemporaryCredentials\Program.cs:line 67
   at Amazon.DocSamples.S3.TempCredExplicitSessionStartTest.ListObjectsAsync() in C:\Code\TestAwsEC2TemporaryCredentials\TestAwsEC2TemporaryCredentials\Program.cs:line 33
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Amazon.DocSamples.S3.TempCredExplicitSessionStartTest.Main() in C:\Code\TestAwsEC2TemporaryCredentials\TestAwsEC2TemporaryCredentials\Program.cs:line 23
```

and here is the original code, with my bucket obviously redacted:

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.SecurityToken;
using Amazon.SecurityToken.Model;

namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
{
    class TempCredExplicitSessionStartTest
    {
        private const string bucketName = "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucketnamegoeshere";
        // Specify your bucket region (an example region is shown).
        private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2;
        private static IAmazonS3 s3Client;
        public static void Main()
        {
            ListObjectsAsync().Wait();
        }

        private static async Task ListObjectsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                // Credentials use the default AWS SDK for .NET credential search chain. 
                // On local development machines, this is your default profile.
                Console.WriteLine("Listing objects stored in a bucket");
                SessionAWSCredentials tempCredentials = await GetTemporaryCredentialsAsync();

                // Create a client by providing temporary security credentials.
                using (s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(tempCredentials, bucketRegion))
                {
                    var listObjectRequest = new ListObjectsRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName
                    };
                    // Send request to Amazon S3.
                    ListObjectsResponse response = await s3Client.ListObjectsAsync(listObjectRequest);
                    List<S3Object> objects = response.S3Objects;
                    Console.WriteLine("Object count = {0}", objects.Count);
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message, s3Exception.InnerException);
            }
            catch (AmazonSecurityTokenServiceException stsException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stsException.Message, stsException.InnerException);
            }
        }

        private static async Task<SessionAWSCredentials> GetTemporaryCredentialsAsync()
        {
            using (var stsClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient())
            {
                var getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest
                {
                    DurationSeconds = 7200 // seconds
                };

                GetSessionTokenResponse sessionTokenResponse =
                              await stsClient.GetSessionTokenAsync(getSessionTokenRequest);

                Credentials credentials = sessionTokenResponse.Credentials;

                var sessionCredentials =
                    new SessionAWSCredentials(credentials.AccessKeyId,
                                              credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                                              credentials.SessionToken);
                return sessionCredentials;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The EC2 that the code is running in has a role associated with it. That role is ec2-test-role. The ec2-test-role has the policy AmazonS3FullAccess applied to it.

What am I missing here? How can I get this to run?

Comment: I decided to try to test whether I could access the instance metadata. Not sure it this has any impact or whether I'm doing the right thing, but I opened a PowerShell in Administrator and ran Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id and its saying that I am unable to connect to the remote server. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: It _might_ be using [IMDSv2 - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html). I wonder if you can change the instance to use Instance Metadata Service v1?

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593693/ec2-private-subnet-cant-reach-169-254-169-254-when-os-is-windows-server-2019 which suggests that it might be a routing issue. It suggests running a powershell script to fix the issue. Script is found here: https://github.com/tuanba2203/CoderLangBam.io/blob/master/fix_ec2_instance_netroutes.ps1. I will give that a try.

Comment: I was successfully able to get connectivity to 169.254.169.254. I'm getting a different error now but I will play a bit more before posting that it's a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there are two problems that I had to address to fix the above issue.

The first was that the EC2 instance resided in it's own separated Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network and there was missing routing between the instance and the metadata that provides the temporary credentials. Of course that is solved by fixing the routing issue which may be beyond many developers, however a PowerShell script found [here](https://github.com/tuanba2203/CoderLangBam.io/blob/master/fix_ec2_instance_netroutes.ps1) can be run in your EC2 instance to fix the connectivity issue.

The second is that the reference example that was provided on the AWS site for .NET is wrong. You don't need to get temporary credentials at all. All you need to do is create a new instance of the S3Client object and it will look after the credentials for you. It looks in the app.config first, but if you don't have app.config, it gets the credentials from the EC2 environment metadata, which was unblocked above.

Finally, if you are still having issues, make sure you have an IAM role associated with your EC2 instance, and make sure that role has a policy that allows read List access to the S3 bucket that you want to obtain the information from.

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.SecurityToken;
using Amazon.SecurityToken.Model;

namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
{
    class TempCredExplicitSessionStartTest
    {
        private const string bucketName = "mys3bucketnamegoeshere";
        
        private static IAmazonS3 s3Client;
        public static void Main()
        {
            ListObjectsAsync().Wait();
        }

        private static async Task ListObjectsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Listing objects stored in a bucket");

                // Create a client using the EC2 temporary security credentials.
                // The AmazonS3Client constructor does the work for you. 
                // You can specify a region but it will use the current region
                // you're running in if you don't specify one.
                using (s3Client = new AmazonS3Client())
                {
                    var listObjectRequest = new ListObjectsRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName
                    };
                    // Send request to Amazon S3.
                    ListObjectsResponse response = await s3Client.ListObjectsAsync(listObjectRequest);
                    List<S3Object> objects = response.S3Objects;
                    Console.WriteLine("Object count = {0}", objects.Count);
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message, s3Exception.InnerException);
            }
            catch (AmazonSecurityTokenServiceException stsException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stsException.Message, stsException.InnerException);
            }
        }

}
```